# Set value into variable in struts1

Tags: java, struts1

I can iterate the list in struts1 using below code :

```
<logic:iterate name="listMsg" id="listMsgId">
<p>
    List Messages <bean:write name="listMsgId"/>
</p>
</logic:iterate>
```

But how can I set variable within this tag.

For example I want to fetch data from the above tag and initialize in some variable.

```
<logic:iterate name="listMsg" id="listMsgId">
<p>
    <%
        String firstName = "Get data from this list";
     %>
    List Messages <bean:write name="listMsgId"/>
</p>
</logic:iterate>
```

How can I achieve the above one using struts1 and java.

Is it possible? If yes then how?

Answer (score 0):

one solution, and imo the better one, is to use jsp jstl. See the example below:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%--@elvariable id="messages" type="java.util.List"--%>

<c:forEach items="${messages.msgList}" var="message" varStatus="st">
    <c:set var="varName" value="varValue"/>
    <p>${message.id}</p>
    <p>${varName}</p> <!-- to print -->
</c:forEach>
```

Hope this helps!